# How can I increase the space between the checkbox and the associated text?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, wpf-controls

I'm using WPF, and I have a CheckBox element with associated text/content. I've changed the FlowDirection to be RightToLeft so that the checkbox appears to the right of the text. But it appears very close to the text. I'd like to increase the spacing between the text and the checkbox, but of course the Margin option changes the outside margins of the whole control.
Thanks for any ideas.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">Activate</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work too:

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0">Activate</TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 18):

[`Padding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.padding.aspx), probably.

[image: Box Model]

See also: [Aligment, Margins and Padding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By default xaml makes the checkbox a void item.
Change the `<Checkbox />` to `<CheckBox></CheckBox>` and inside the tag add a textblock to add the content. Add padding to change the alignment with the box.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ChkExcel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 3 0 3">
          <TextBlock Padding="10 2 0 0">Microsoft Office Excel</TextBlock>
        </CheckBox>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: Hi Nathan, sure i have added an explanation